# ¿Cómo manejar herencia múltiple con varios módulos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, herencia

Saben porque el terminal me retorna solamente

> *Ancho: 4, Alto: 4= 16 Color: <super: <class 'Color'>, NULL>*

Intento imprimir el área de un cuadrado, pero solo me imprime el total del área no el color.

### Módulo 1

```
class FiguraGeometrica(object):
    def __init__(self,ancho,alto):
        self.__ancho=ancho
        self.__alto=alto
        
    def get_ancho(self):
        return self.__ancho
        
    def set_ancho(self,ancho):
        self.__ancho=ancho 
        
    def get_alto(self):
        return self.__alto
        
    def set_alto(self,alto):
        self.__alto=alto
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "Ancho: "+ str(self.__ancho)+", Alto: "+str(self.__alto)+"= "+str(self.__ancho*self.__alto)
```

### Módulo 2

```
class Color(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.__color=color
        
    def get_color(self):
        return self.__color
        
    def set_color(self,color):
        self.__color=color
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__color)
```

### Módulo 3

```
from figura_geometrica import FiguraGeometrica
from color import Color

class Cuadrado(FiguraGeometrica, Color):
    def __init__(self, lado, color):
        FiguraGeometrica.__init__(self, lado, lado)
        Color.__init__(self, color)
        
    def __str__(self): 
        return super().__str__()+" Color: "+super(Color).__str__()
```

### Módulo 4

```
from cuadrado import Cuadrado
from rectangulo import Rectángulo

cuadrado = Cuadrado(4,"Rojo")
print(cuadrado)
```

Si me pudieran ayudar, se los agradecería.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de darte la respuesta, te voy a comentar formas de hacer tú código más "Pythonico", es decir, como se suele escribir en Python y además hacer algunas aclaraciones:

1. En Python, al contrario que otros idiomas como C++ por ejemplo, no existen los métodos privados. Todos los métodos son públicos, poner **una barra baja** (no dos), es la forma de indicar al programador, que es un método es privado y que no debería tocar eso.
2. No se suelen usar los Getters y los Setters como en otros lenguajes, si no que los atributos de la clase se consultan y se modifican de manera pública.
3. Una regla no escrita en Python, es que se debe escribir la menor cantidad de código siempre que sea posible

Una vez dicho lo anterior, hay que decir, que "hackeando python" podemos crear clases privadas (no es recomendable, salvo que sea absolutamente necesario), y que también se pueden crear getters y setters con el decorador `@property`.

Una vez aclarado, todo esto, vamos con tu ejercicio, al que le he hecho algunas modificaciones, aplicando lo anteriormente expuesto. En este caso, yo lo he quedado todo en el mismo .py ; pero tú puedes hacerte los imports como has ido haciendo, sin problemas

```
#CLASE PADRE FIGURA GEOMÉTRICA
#____________________________________________________________________
class FiguraGeometrica:
    def __init__(self, ancho, alto):
        self.ancho=ancho
        self.alto=alto
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "Ancho: "+ str(self.ancho)+", Alto: "+str(self.alto)+", Area = "+str(self.ancho*self.alto)


#CLASE PADRE FIGURA COLOR
#____________________________________________________________________
class Color:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color=color
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "Color: " + str(self.color)


#CLASE HIJA CUADRADO: aquí es donde están los errores
#____________________________________________________________________
class Cuadrado(FiguraGeometrica, Color):

    #instanciamos totas las propiedades necesarias para las distintas clases
    def __init__(self, ancho, alto, color):
        super().__init__(ancho, alto)
        super(FiguraGeometrica, self).__init__(color)

    #Ponemos en el super, FiguraGeométrica en vez de Color
    def __str__(self): 
        return super().__str__() + ", " + super(FiguraGeometrica, self).__str__()


cuadrado = Cuadrado(4, 4, "Rojo")
print(cuadrado)
```

Lo que he hecho:

1. He quitado las dobles barras bajas `__` ya que las dobles barras son para métodos especiales.
2. He quitado los getters y los setters ya que no son necesario para este caso de uso. Puedes consultar las variables así: `print(cuadrado.color)` y modificar el color `cuadrado.color = "verde"`
3. He añadido "Area" al método especial `__str__` de `FiguraGeometrica` para que se visualice mejor

### Tu problema.

Una vez hecha esta larga introducción, vamos con tú problema. Todo radica en tu clase hija cuadrado.

1. Tu instancias, un atributo "lado" el cual no existe, tienes que instanciar tus atributos "alto" y "ancho"
2. Ya que usas el método super en `__str__` por qué no usarlo también el `__init__` ? Aunque tú forma de hacerlo es totalmente correcta, y se ve en muchos casos, la función `super()` nos permitiría hacer **inyección de dependencias** (dependency injection). Esto nos permite introducir una clase entre padre e hijo, por ejemplo aquí podría ser interesante introducir, otra clase entre `FiguraGeometricaa` y `Cuadrado` que se llamase por ejemplo `CuatroLados` ya que el área de el resto de figuras que no tienen 4 lados, su formula es distinta
3. Por último, el método especial `__str__`: `super()` dando una definición de andar por casa lo que significa es: "después inicia lo siguiente". Por ejemplo cuando lo uso en el `__init__` al principio lo uso con el propio `__init__` lo que le estoy diciendo a python es "Inicia el constructor de la clase cuadrado y **después inicia el siguiente** constructor que haya tras la clase Cuadrado, en este caso es el constructor de FiguraGeometrica y por último, **después inicia el siguiente** constructor que haya tras FiguraGeometrica, en este caso Color".

En el método `__str__` es igual. No puedes poner `super(Color)` por que le estas diciendo a Python que busque la siguiente clase a `Color` y no hay ninguna clase más, ya que las dos clases que heredas son `Figurageometrica` y `Color`. Por lo tanto has de poner `FiguraGeometrica` para que te traiga `Color`.

### Getters y Setters.

Como te he comentado, no se suele hacer uso de los Getters y Setters en Python, salvo que sea absolutamente necesario, por ejemplo en validación de datos, descriptors, etc. En el caso de que lo quieras hacer, puedes usar el decorador `@property`.

```
#CLASE PADRE FIGURA GEOMÉTRICA
#____________________________________________________________________
class FiguraGeometrica:
    def __init__(self, ancho, alto):
        self._ancho=ancho
        self._alto=alto

    @property
    def ancho(self):
        return self._ancho

    @ancho.setter
    def ancho(self, value):
        self._ancho = value

    @ancho.deleter
    def ancho(self):
        del self._ancho


    @property
    def alto(self):
        return self._alto

    @alto.setter
    def alto(self, value):
        self._alto = value

    @alto.deleter
    def alto(self):
        del self._alto

    def __str__(self):
        return "Ancho: "+ str(self._ancho)+", Alto: "+str(self._alto)+", Area = "+str(self._ancho*self._alto)


#CLASE PADRE FIGURA COLOR
#____________________________________________________________________
class Color:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self._color=color

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, value):
        self._color = value

    @color.deleter
    def color(self, value):
        del self._color
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "Color: " + str(self._color)



#CLASE HIJA CUADRADO:
#____________________________________________________________________
class Cuadrado(FiguraGeometrica, Color):

    def __init__(self, ancho, alto, color):
        super().__init__(ancho, alto)
        super(FiguraGeometrica, self).__init__(color)

    def __str__(self): 
        return super().__str__() + ", " + super(FiguraGeometrica, self).__str__()


cuadrado = Cuadrado(4, 4, "Rojo")
print(cuadrado)

cuadrado.color = 'Verde'
print(cuadrado.color)
print(cuadrado.alto)
```

Como puedes ver aquí accedemos al atributo `_color` mediante `.color`. Aunque como he dicho antes en Python todos los métodos y atributos son públicos, por lo que puedes seguir accediendo a través de `_color`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias estaba adentrándome en el mundo de python estudiando está cuarentena agradezco tu aporte mucho

Comment: De nada @CesarVigil ! Como eres nuevo, posiblemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow, es dandole una puntuación positiva a la pregunta y por qué no, si te ha parecido una respuesta que ha ayudado a tu problema, marcar la pregunta como "respuesta correcta". Esto no solo agradecerá mi ayuda, si no que además, posicionará bien tu pregunta y si en el futuro, alguien tiene una duda parecida a la tuya, tendrá más facilidades para encontrarla :)

Answer (score -1):

## Modulo 1

```
class FiguraGeometrica:
    
    def __init__(self, ancho, alto):
        self.__ancho = ancho 
        self.__alto = alto
        
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Ancho: '+ str(self.__ancho) + ', Alto: '+ str(self.__alto) 
      
    def get_ancho(self):
        return self.__ancho
            
    def set_ancho(self, ancho):
        self.__ancho = ancho  
        
    def get_alto(self):
            return self.__alto
            
    def set_alto(self, alto):
        self.__alto = alto
```

## Modulo 2

```
class Color:
    
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.__color = color
        
    def get_color(self):
        return self.__color
            
    def set_color(self, color):
        self.__color = color
# Modulo 3
from figura_geometrica import FiguraGeometrica
from color import Color

class Cuadrado(FiguraGeometrica, Color):
    def __init__(self, lado, color):
        FiguraGeometrica.__init__(self, lado, lado)
        Color.__init__(self, color)
    
    def area(self):
        return self.get_ancho() * self.get_alto()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return FiguraGeometrica.__str__(self) + ', Color: '+self.get_color()
```

## Modulo 4

```
from cuadrado import Cuadrado

cuadrado = Cuadrado(5, 'Azul')
print(cuadrado)
print('Area del Cuadrado:',cuadrado.area())
```

Comment: explica tu respuesta, esto para saber que es lo que hace